# Looking for Open Source Java Projects that use JUnit and Ant

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, open-source, junit

I am currently doing some research and I am looking for *open source Java projects* that use *JUnit* and *Ant*. Ideally I would like to have projects that vary in size/complexity/domain as well as the test suite coverage.

I seem to be having a hard time finding suitable open source projects that fit these criteria:

- Project has a number of JUnit test cases
- All the JUnit test cases can be ran from a single test class (i.e., a JUnit TestSuite)
- The project uses Ant for building and testing

I am sure that the community would benefit from a list of usable open source projects fitting the aforementioned criteria. It is always possible to learn from projects that use these technologies. As a side bonus researchers could also quickly identify suitable open source projects for their research.

---

#### The following are suitable open source project according to the criteria:

- [JGAP](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/)
- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [JSR-166](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/index.html)
- [mark4j](http://marc4j.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just bumped onto [JSR-166](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=166), the Java Specification Request for the various Concurrency utilities. The [source code](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/index.html) has an Ant task at the top level and a pretty extensive JUnit-based testsuite. As an added benefit, the units under test are actually classes that are included in the JDK, which has a couple of advantages:

- They are very well documented, which is not usually the case.
- Since they are part of the JDK, they should already be familiar to most experienced Java programmers. Understanding supporting infrastructure such as a build system or a test suite is hard enough without having to understand the actual codebase as well.

That said, there are a couple of issues as well:

- The current code is bleeding edge - literally! The current version already requires at least Java 7 and seems geared towards Java 8. You might want to retrieve an older version of the code that is closer to the Java versions used in production.
- The JSR-166 source code is not very well organized. The obvious issue I encountered was the lack of a singular package root and an overabundance of classes that belong to the default package. You have been warned...

PS: This question is not very suitable for StackOverflow, since it does not have *one* answer. I provided this answer to point out an obvious repository of code, i.e. Java itself, that inexperienced programmers tend to ignore completely, since they consider it part of the system...

Comment: I understand that this question is not well suited for SO, but I was unable to make the question a *community wiki*. I intend to update the main post with a good list of open source Java programs that use JUnit and Ant.

Answer (score 1):

[marc4j](http://marc4j.tigris.org/) fits your requirements. You can download the project, unpack, then compile and run JUnit tests using the included ant script.